# Screens in Folders within Expression Blend Sketchflow

Tags: sketchflow, expression-blend-3

Is there a way to put screens in a folder int he project view and have them available in the SketchFlow Map? I can create the Screens but they are not available in the Sketchflow Map.  It is appearing that all of the Screens have to exist at the root of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I answered this on twitter for you already, but for the benefit of people who might find this question, the answer is that you can add them to the SketchFlow Map, but they must be User Controls.

1. Create your folder
2. Create a new user control
3. Right click the user control in the project panel and pick "Create Screen in SketchFlow Map"

This also works with existing user controls.

If you wish to move an existing screen into a folder, you must first remove it from the map, move it into a folder, and then add it to the map again.